# WPF Clipping a child control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have  `Grid` in WPF whose child control I want to clip. I tried setting negative margins for the child control but it keeps going out of the `Grid`. What can I do to clip out portions of the child control?

Comment: Post your XAML for a repro...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the Clip property of the Child or use `<Grid ClipToBounds="True">`